# Открыть стороннее приложение в области своего приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, auto

Раздумываю над собственным android auto на базе пересобранной версии 12. Допустим я создам свой launcher под экран 15... 17 дюймов с основным интерфейсом отображения состояния авто и окнами настроек. Возможно ли реализовать механизм, при котором я смогу в регулируемой по габаритом области интерфейса запускать сторонние приложения, например яндекс навигатор, браузер, chrome и тд? Либо чтобы открываемые приложения были окнами фиксированного (моим приложением) размера и  размещались в конкретном месте. Разрабатывать планирую в Android Studio. Требуется создать что-то похожее на интерфейс центрального экрана Tesla Model 3.